# ASP.NET MVC3 Google Analytics integration

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, google-analytics

I would like to graph/ or pull in data from Google analytics to my ASP.NET MVC 3 web app. is there a MVC helper out there to do this? any info greatly appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the google analytic api that you can use to download analytics data in the form of google data api feeds.

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/

reference: http://www.bryaneisenberg.com/2009/10/google-analytics-plugins-hacks/

Answer (score 3):

In ASP.Net MVC3 you have [Analytics Helper](http://www.asp.net/webmatrix/tutorials/14-analyzing-traffic). That should be able to help you.

Comment: Well, I just noticed that you are not looking to implement analytics, but to pull that data.